# Sql Server - how to get the least qualifying record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

How to get the least row base on the "age" I am passing to the query?

And that age is not part of minAge or maxage in the table..

example of my Stored Proc

```
declare @MyAge int;
select @MyAge = 21;

select *
from Mytable
where ( AssuranceId = 9 and MemberTypeId = 1 )
and  (  @MyAge between MinAge and MaxAge ) -- obvious this will return nothing
```

-- But I want it to work it out to return that row with null values on min and max age row --- if it does find a qualifying row

-- So it should return row id: 16
or Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: But then - if I pass @MyAge = 38 , it will give me ... the null age rows record, yet I do have MinAge = 38 record ?

>>Tim Biegeleisen- it doesnt allow me to comment on your reply/ answer :(

Comment: Some thing like this ` and  ( @MyAge >= MinAge OR MinAge is NULL) OR (@MyAge <= MaxAge OR MaxAge is NULL ) ` ?

Comment: That's because your `BETWEEN` needs both MinAge and MaxAge to become true.

Comment: So what's the better approach ? - to achieve this

Comment: Thank y'all for trying  - I think I wanted the impossible .
 -- I figured that the solution is too make sure that :
>> There is both MinAge anf MaxAge in a table
otherwise 1 record that has Both Null values in Min & MaxAge for a specific asssurance and MemberType

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @MyAge int;
select @MyAge = 21;

select *
from Mytable
where ( AssuranceId = 9 and MemberTypeId = 1 )
and  (isnull(@MyAge, 0) between isnull(MinAge, 0) and isnull(MaxAge, 200))
```

**UPD**

In case you want the one most specific record you can add order clause:

```
declare @MyAge int;
select @MyAge = 38;

select top 1 *
from Mytable t
where ( AssuranceId = 9 and MemberTypeId = 1 )
and  (isnull(@MyAge, 0) between isnull(MinAge, 0) and isnull(MaxAge, 200))
order by
  t.MinAge desc, t.MaxAge desc
;
```

That gives you a record with MinAge = 38 not with the null value.

Comment: But the `( AssuranceId = 9 and MemberTypeId = 1 )` is only supposed to return anything if no row at all matches the BETWEEN part.

Comment: This will return records matching `IS NULL` even if there are _also_ range matching records.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your query, if I understand it correctly, is that you want to retain all records where `@MyAge` is between the `MinAge` and `MaxAge`, except in the case where there are no records, in which case you want records for which `MinAge` and `MaxAge` are both `NULL`.  I see no way around using a subquery here.  I have a subquery in the `WHERE` clause which checks if there any range matching records.  If so, then it uses your previous `WHERE` condition, and if not, then it uses a check `IS NULL` on the age columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM Mytable
WHERE (AssuranceId = 9 AND MemberTypeId = 1) AND TRUE =
    CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Mytable WHERE @MyAge BETWEEN MinAge AND MaxAge) > 0
        THEN (@MyAge >= MinAge AND @MyAge <= MaxAge)
        ELSE (MinAge IS NULL AND MaxAge IS NULL)
    END
```

The penalty for the subquery in this case should be small since it is not correlated.

Comment: Error in your sql query: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BETWEEN'

Comment: @BhekiNzuza Add parentheses around the `THEN` clause.

Comment: Thats the 1st thing I did .. but no luck

Comment: Get rid of `BETWEEN`

Comment: Get rid of "BETWEEN" ... and how is the comparison gonna happening without that "between"  >>  THEN ( @MyAge BETWEEN MinAge AND MaxAge )

Comment: Wow this is really hard communicating with you.  Replace `BETWEEN` with less than and greater than operators.

Comment: Apologies man, please bear with me! .. I did that it doesnt work ... I think the query don't like "Then ...ELSE" in there

Comment: Try one more time.  After this I will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a common table expression (cte) that selects rows where AssuranceId = 9 and MemberTypeId = 1.

With that cte, if the `BETWEEN` condition is true, return that row. `OR` if such row doesn't exist at all.

```
with cte as
(
    select *
    from Mytable
    where AssuranceId = 9 and MemberTypeId = 1
)
select * from cte
where (isnull(@MyAge, 0) between isnull(MinAge, 0) and isnull(MaxAge, 200)
       AND (MinAge is not null or MaxAge is not null))
   OR NOT EXISTS (select * from cte 
                  where isnull(@MyAge, 0) between isnull(MinAge, 0) and isnull(MaxAge, 200)
                    and (MinAge is not null or MaxAge is not null))
```

Comment: Jarth - remember there are also other Assurance amounts , so the query must be "assuarnce and member type specific

Comment: @BhekiNzuza, Alright, I wasn't quite sure if that mattered as long as the age was correct. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks -  this was close -- but it returns the age of 65  ...not where Min and Max age is null row ..... for that that specific assurance and memberType ...I will play around with this query

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
select top (1) * -- you might be excepting only one row here by preference
from Mytable
where ( AssuranceId = 9 and MemberTypeId = 1 )
and  ( -- added 
        (@MyAge between MinAge and MaxAge ) -- first preference
       OR( MinAge IS NULL AND MaxAge<=@MyAge) --Second preference
       OR( MaxAge IS NULL AND MinAge>=@MyAge) -- third preference
       OR(MinAge IS NULL AND MaxAge Is NUll) -- Last preference
   )-- added
```

Comment: Moumit - this returns a wrong record ( wrong assurance Id: 1, membertypeId :3 )
take into account that - There are other assurances and membertypes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
declare @MyAge int;
select @MyAge = 21;
select * from Mytable
where ( AssuranceId = 9 and MemberTypeId = 1 )
and  (MinAge is NULL OR MinAge <= @MyAge) AND (MaxAge is NULL OR MaxAge >= @MyAge)
```